# How to get the gamma value of QImage

Tags: qt, qimage

In QImageWriter there is an option for setting the gamma value if the image but i want to know how to get the present gamma value so i can represent it in my histogram of the image .

Comment: Gamma value depends on image format. So you can't apply/get gamma value on QImage, because QImage - it's Qt object for image representation.

Comment: first i thank you fro replying .. is there any possible way in qt or i have to rely it on OpenCv or something else u  can suggest ..